# edit Create View generated by Database-First Model in ASP MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, datepicker

i have this create view and it generated codes....

```
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeId, "Employee")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("EmployeeId", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date,"Date")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
        </div>
```

upon running it, it automatically created textboxes for inputs... what i can't do is to force the textbox of date to become a datepicker...

i can do that on simple inputs,

```
 <input class="datepicker">
```

i  already have a script for the datepicker.. i just need to make the input class of date to be also datepicker... (i cant see an input in the code generated where i can add the class="datepicker")

Comment: making the class of the div of date equal to "datepicker" would only result to an instantly visible calendar under the textbox of date and it doesnt pass the selected date to the textbox

Answer (score 0):

You could add the `datepicker` class to the containing div:

```
<div class="editor-field datepicker">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
</div>
```

and then simply adapt your jQuery selector so that it applies the date picker either to input elements with the class `datepicker` or to input elements contained within some element with this class:

```
$('.datepicker, .datepicker input[type="text"]').datepicker();
```

Another possibility is to use a [custom metadata provider](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-_2D00_-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx) which allows you to apply additional HTML attributes such as css class to input fields generated with the `EditorFor` helper. All you have to do is decorate your view model property with a custom attribute.

Comment: there are already two calendars under the textbox of date, one permanent, and the other one is the normal one which only shows when you click the textbox

Comment: And what is the problem? All you have to do is adapt your jQuery selectors in order to attach the plugins to the proper elements.